# PHP error in form spam prevention

Tags: php, html, forms, spam

I have a problem with this code returning nothing but a blank page... I have followed several different tutorials to try and get this working, I am not a proficient PHP coder at all - But do have a little understanding. My server however, doesn't show error messages. So pinpointing this is rather hard for me to do!

I added this top section here to prevent spam using a hidden field on the html page that posts to this email page.

```
<?php
$if(isset($_POST['subject'],$_POST['Customer'],$_POST['Email'],$_POST['Phone'],$_POST['Comment'],$_POST['Product'],$_POST['Amount'],$_POST['Valid'])) {
    $if(isset($_POST['Name']) && !empty($_POST['Name'])) {
        echo "Spam Detected!";
        Die();
    }
```

Here is the email part that is supposed to send email once the above section determines that field "name" is empty.

```
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $name = $_POST['Customer'];
    $from = $_POST['Email'];
    $phone = $_POST['Phone'];
    $message = $_POST['Comment'];
    $prod = $_POST['Product'];
    $cash = $_POST['Amount'];
    $valid = $_POST['Valid'];
    $to = "email@email.com";

    $body = 'HTML EMAIL CONTENT HERE...';

    $headers .= "From: $from " . "Subject";
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
    mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
}
?>
```

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: can you add the form to the code please?

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` use this code may be its helpfull

Comment: You should enable error reporting like @EhsanIlahi says. There's a lot of errors in your code. Like for example: Starting if statements with a dollar sign ??

Comment: $if is nothing but error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this i see your code you use **$if** try if without $

```
if(isset($_POST['subject'],$_POST['Customer'],$_POST['Email'],$_POST['Phone'],$_POST['Comment'],$_POST['Product'],$_POST['Amount'],$_POST['Valid'])) {
            if(isset($_POST['Name']) && !empty($_POST['Name'])) {
                echo "Spam Detected!";
                Die();
            }
}
```